# How to force update

Tags: apt, updates

So I've been getting this error:
`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/f-muriana/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Can someone please help?
Oh, I'm on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The PPA in the error message hasn't been updated since 2014 therefore it couldn't possibly support Ubuntu 20.04. Simply remove it. You can use Software & Updates > Other software .

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find this line.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/f-muriana/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu focal Release
```

Comment it (change that line with this line)

```
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/f-muriana/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu focal Release
```

save the file by pressing ctrl+O press enter. exit with ctrl+x

now run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Most likely this line is not in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`